# Touchpad auto-disabled in kali 2.0

Tags: kali-linux, touchpad

I have a dual boot in my acer aspire v3 with Kali Linux 2.0 and windows 10 edu version. Each time I login to windows my touch-pad works perfectly fine but when I login to Kali I have to enable the touch-pad in each startup and also the touch to tap function is disabled. is there any method to solve it for good?

Answer (score -1):

Run this:

```
modprobe -r psmouse
modprobe psmouse proto=impc
```

Comment: Some information about why this is a solution to the problem would be great.